# Finder tag search exclusive

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag, smart-folders

I am using tags to label all my documents in Finder, and Smart Folders to organise them, but I'm running into a roadblock.

Lets say I have a bunch of documents with the tag "fruits", and some -- but not all -- documents also have additional tags like "apples", "oranges" etc. There is an unknown number of additional tags.  I want to create a Smart Folder containing file that have only the fruits tag, and nothing else.  How do you do such an exclusive search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a *Finder* window at the folder in which you wish to search.  Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to open a Spotlight search window, which will target that folder.  There is a drop-down list that will have `"Kind"` selected:

[image: Spotlight Search Window Bar in macOS]

You will want to change this to `"Raw Query"`, which, if it isn't available in the drop-down list, you can add by selecting `"Other..."` at the bottom of the list, then selecting it in the panel of search attributes that is presented:

[image: Selecting Search Attributes in macOS]

As your raw query, enter the following noting the triple equality:

```
kMDItemUserTags==='fruits'
```

Then click `"Save"` to create your Smart Folder.

---

Here's a demonstration using the coloured tags in *Finder* on the contents of the following folder:

[image]

This finds files tagged ***only*** *Green* (triple equality):

[image]

This finds files tagged *Green* ± other tags (double equality):

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted files tagged 'fruits' and 'vegetables' only?

Comment: @user330662 Your phrasing is ambiguous so I don't completely know what you want. Hopefully, you're looking for files tagged with **either** `fruits` **or** `vegetables` (but not both nor any other tag): `kMDItemUserTags==='fruits' || kMDItemUserTags==='vegetables'`. If you wanted files also tagged `fruits` or `vegetables` or both, the closest I can manage is: `(kMDItemUserTags==='fruits' || kMDItemUserTags==='vegetables') || (kMDItemUserTags=='fruits' && kMDItemUserTags=='vegetables')`, *however*, this _doesn't_ eliminate files tagged `fruits` **and** `vegetables` **and** any other tag.